# Clarification of Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Let's say I have an interval consisting of 10 elements and I calculate the Wronskian of the given functions. Out of the interval of 10 elements, substitution of 9 of the elements in the equation obtained after applying determinant(Wronskian) results in 0. But there is one number in the interval that doesn't lead the determinant value to zero. Would I still consider those functions as linear independent and also consider them to form the general solution for the ODE?

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "an interval consisting of 10 elements."  Isn't an interval a thing like $a<x<b$, and would have infinitely many elements?

Comment: Perhaps you mean: "at ten points belonging to the interval"? Then no, the functions cannot be solutions of any linear homogeneous ODE with the leading coefficient $1$ and the remaining coefficients continuous on the interval. But the functions are linearly independent: their linear dependence would result in their Wrońskian constantly equal to zero.